# Nodemails give me TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

i try to send beautifuls mails in Node.js with Nodemails but it gives the error when i add a template.

there is my code

```
require('dotenv').config();

const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const hbs = require('nodemailer-handlebars');
const log = console.log;

// Step 1
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: 'hacktonthon@gmail.com',
      pass: '......'
      }
});

// Step 2
transporter.use('compile', hbs({
    viewEngine: 'express',
    viewPath: './views/'
}));


// Step 3
let mailOptions = {
    from: 'hacktonthon@gmail.com', // TODO: email sender
    to: 'pgmendormi@gmail.com', // TODO: email receiver
    subject: 'Nodemailer - Test',
    text: 'Wooohooo it works!!',
    template: 'test',
    // context: {
    //     name: 'Accime Esterling'
    // } // send extra values to template
};

// Step 4
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        return log(err);
    }
    return log('Email sent!!!');
});
```

It functions when i delete the transporter.use (that send me an email)  and the template test, but when i try to add it that gives me this:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11)
    at Object.resolve (path.js:1080:7)
    at ExpressHandlebars._resolveLayoutPath (/home/guigui/synapture/my_hackathon/formulaire/node_modules/nodemailer-handlebars/node_modules/express-handlebars/lib/express-handlebars.js:342:17)
    at ExpressHandlebars.<anonymous> (/home/guigui/synapture/my_hackathon/formulaire/node_modules/nodemailer-handlebars/node_modules/express-handlebars/lib/express-handlebars.js:223:35)
```

I have a test.handlebars who is really classic, "just an hello world"
I'm quite new with Js, and i dont understand the error. Is it a problem in my code?

Thanks for your answers and sorry for my english.

Comment: Check out [this](https://github.com/yads/nodemailer-express-handlebars/issues/26#issuecomment-502520611) issue. It appears to be the same problem as yours.